# Why doesn't scan(/\w/) count the same as gsub(/\s+/, '').length?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to count the characters in a text file excluding white spaces. My thought was to use `scan`; however, the tutorial I am reading uses `gsub`. There is a difference in output between the two, and I was wondering why. Here are the two code blocks; the `gsub` version is the one that's giving me the correct output:

```
total_characters_nospaces = text.gsub(/\s+/, '').length
puts "#{total_characters_nospaces} characters excluding spaces."
```

And the other one:

```
chars = 0
totes_chars_no = text.scan(/\w/){|everything| chars += 1 }
puts chars
```

Comment: show us the actual input string!!

Answer (score 5):

The opposite of `\s` is not `\w` - it is `\S`.

`\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. It does not include many other characters such as punctuation.

`\S` is the exact opposite of `\s` - it includes any character that is not whitespace.

Comment: Thanks Amber. This was the perfect explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Now that your question has been answered, here are a couple other ways you could do it:

```
s = "now is the time    for all good"

s.count "^\s" # => 22

s.each_char.reduce(0) { |count, c| count + (c =~ /\S/ ? 1 : 0) } # => 22
```